# Azure Storage Data Movement Library copy is much slower than AzCopy

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azcopy

I have next test setup:

1. One test Azure blob storage account
2. Local folder with ~3000 small files (200 bytes each)

When I execute `azcopy` command:

```
azcopy copy --recursive "c:\localDir\*" "https://BLOBConnectionString"
```

it takes ~2 seconds to copy data.

When I do next c# code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 32;
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 32;
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("https://BLOBConnectionString");

CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("container");
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

CloudBlobDirectory destinationBlob = container.GetDirectoryReference("data");
await TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(@"c:\localDir\", destinationBlob);
```

It takes ~1 **minute** to copy same amount of data.
I expect to have approximately same latency results for c# code base.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

**Code:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace fastercpy
{
    class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string storageConnectionString = "< Connection string >";
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            string sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Documents\\Venkat";
            CloudBlobDirectory destinationBlob = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("data");

            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
            // Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
            SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();
            context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
            });
            var task=TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(sourcePath, destinationBlob);
            task.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

you have been used
**`TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 32`**  ,So try to use  **`TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;`** in your code it will speed up process.

The Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library was created for fast uploading, downloading, and copying of Azure Storage Blob and File.

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Transfer data with the Data Movement library for .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library)